# How cvqueryframe() retrieves frame from camera as per set frame rate?

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

I want to know how cvQueryFrame() captures and provides frames at a previously set frame rate.

In my program, I am capturing a new frame at the start of each iteration of while(1) loop. I have set Frame rate to 1 Frame per sec. Hence time required for completion of one interation should be 1sec or more. But as I am calculating time for each iteration using cvGetTickCount() function, it shows 250ms to 350ms time spent for each iteration.

This is affecting my other conditions depending on time.
I suspect that cvQueryFrame() is not working according to set frame rate.

Can anyone tell me what maybe the reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

getTickCount counts *cpu time*, also only for the current thread. ( so when you utter a 'sleep' command or do any io, it won't get counted this way )

to properly calculate fps, you'd need another kind of timer, that counts *wall time* instead ( unfortunately, we're getting pretty much os-dependant here ).

also, it might pretty much be that your requested frame rate is not properly respected by the cam-driver.

the whole highgui framework was more made for 'ease of use' ...

ohh, btw, please move over to the c++ api. they stopped developing the old c-api you're using already 4 years ago, its only around for maintenance, and you probably should not develop any new things with it.

Comment: It is not like that cvGetTickCount is showing false values. I have printed time value in while loop. This value is getting printed 3-4 times in a second. So it is obvious that frame retrieval is not going at the rate of 1 FPS. Then is it cam-driver issue or something else?